# C++ unable to read line by line a file via wstring utf-8

Tags: c++

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    std::wstring wstr;
    std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::deque<std::wstring> lines, words;
    std::wifstream wif(L"C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/ConsoleApplication1/x64/Debug/data.txt");
    if (wif.is_open())
    {
        std::wstringstream wss;
        wss << wif.rdbuf();
        wstr = wss.str();
        wif.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Не удалось открыть файл!";
    }
    {
        std::wstringstream wss(wstr);
        std::wstring temp;
        while (std::getline(wss, temp, L'\n'))
            lines.push_back(temp);
    }
    {
        for (std::wstring i : lines)
        {
            std::wstringstream wss(i);
            std::wstring temp;
            while (std::getline(wss, temp, L' '))
                words.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    std::wcout << words[6];
}
```

```
01.01.2014 Старт Кошелёк 990 Изначально в кошельке было 990 руб
01.01.2014 Старт Карта 7000 А на карте 7000
20.09.2014 Кошелёк Проезд 70 Заплатил за проезд
20.09.2014 Кошелёк Базар 500 Купил фруктов на базаре
asd
2014-09-21 Карта Книги 770.31 Купил книжку по карточке
2014-09-21 Карта Кошелёк 770.31
21.02.2014 Карта Кошелёк 1000 Снял тысячу в банкомате
- - - - -
```

UPD. I need to skip lines with invalid date, invalid format... I forgot my iss... in order to fix line by line appending to deque... we do not care about commentary existance we care about existance 4 first items like date, source, destination, amount..

Comment: You may want to post to [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I trust this community more.

Answer (score 1):

Since the comment text has spaces in it, use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>` to read it, eg:

```cpp
if (!((iss >> date_ >> source_ >> destination_ >> amount_) && getline(iss, comment_)))
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
if (!(iss >> date_ >> source_ >> destination_ >> amount_)) 
{ 
    continue; 
}
if (!getline(iss, comment_))
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I still stuck at being unable to read anything.  What is really surprises me.

Comment: @Lith are you saying that `while (std::getline(infile, line))` is not reading anything at all?

Comment: I found some other stackoverflow answers, thankfully I am still unable to parse line by line this file. I only got one element a first line and not fully. My output is : ```Файл прочитан, закрываем!01.01.2014 Старт```

Comment: @Lith what's with the `for ` loop that is removing `L'\0'` characters? After UTF-8 decoding, a text file shouldn't have any null characters in it. Besides, your `while` loop is calling `getline()` with `L'\0'` for the delimiter, so `wline` won't have any `L'\0'` in it anyway, and you not even using the stripped `convert` for anything, so the `for` loop is completely wasted. Also, your outer `while` loop should be calling `getline()` with `L'\n'` as the delimiter, not `L'\0'`.